# Loop to LINQ Conversion -

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, subsonic

Ok I have the following, set-up and working great. These lines of code should do a conversion from DAL Entity (Subsonic) to a ViewModel.

```
    IList<ProductOptionModel> OptionsRetData = new List<ProductOptionModel>();

    foreach (var CurProductOption in this.ProductOptions)
    {
        OptionsRetData.Add(CurProductOption.ToDataModel());
    }

    returnData.Options = OptionsRetData.AsEnumerable();
```

I'd like to convert this to a LINQ single line statment and came up with the following.

```
returnData.Options = this.ProductOptions.Select(o => o.ToDataModel());
```

and am recieving the following error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Sequence contains no matching element
```

So why does the first statment work but not the LINQ and, what steps can I take to resolve it.

> Stack Trace
>
> at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    at
>   SubSonic.Extensions.Database.Load[T](IDataReader
>   rdr, T item, List`1 ColumnNames)    at
>   SubSonic.Extensions.Database.ToEnumerable[T](IDataReader
>   rdr, List`1 ColumnNames)    at
>   SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute[T](QueryCommand`1
>   query, Object[] paramValues)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure )    at
>   SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1.GetEnumerator()

Maybe this is to do with subsonic?

Comment: What's the call stack of the exception?

Comment: What is the return type of ToDataModel()?

Comment: @Dave Swersky - Return type is ProductOptionModel

Comment: I dont think 'select' method throw any error. did you used any 'single' method?

Comment: I also have gotten similar error. Double check if your return type is the same for Options collection and your ProductOptions is not null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is that it's not working because you've changed the time at which the query is materialized. Change the code to this instead:

```
returnData.Options = this.ProductOptions.Select(o => o.ToDataModel()).ToList();
```

That will force the query to be evaluated at the same time it was before.

EDIT: Your stack trace is showing `First()` being called somehow, but we haven't got anything about that in the code you've shown... any ideas where that's happening?

EDIT: I've realised the difference - and I'm foolish for not doing so before. You want to force the projection to be done in-process:

```
returnData.Options = this.ProductOptions
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(o => o.ToDataModel())
                         .ToList();
```

That extra call to `AsEnumerable` means it'll be the `Enumerable.Select` overload which gets called, making it equivalent to your original code.

Comment: @Jon SKeet - Thanks for the reply. Adding the .ToList() results int he same error. (Just on that line now rather than at the VIEW)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sneeky suspicion that this is to do with SubSonic. As I make no actual call to .First();

Comment: @Jon Skeet - There is a reason you have such a high rep. Thanks again, this worked. Is there anywhere I can read up a little more about what you have written?

Comment: @Pino: its weird. sorry for _bad_ suggestions

Comment: @cem dont be sorry it wasnt bad, i appriciate you trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

As i said you're using First method. you may want to change it to FirstOrDefault. it will be solved. *or* do you able to change?

> Stack Trace
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First

Comment: as I said, I am not directly calling that. This seems to be deep in the subsonic files. Maybe thats causing the issue?

Comment: yep. its why this happening. edit. maybe using try catch statements'll fix this. did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ProductOptions.Select(o => o.ToDataModel()).ToList<ProductOptionModel>();
```

Comment: Same problem when using the example line.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to check for the length of **this.ProductOptions** before the LINQ statement.

So maybe (revised without check for null):

```
returnData.Options = (this.ProductOptions.Length > 0) ? this.ProductOptions.Select(o => o.ToDataModel()) : new List<ProductOptionModel>().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Maybe no need to check for null.  The loop works because with length 0, the flow of the program never enters the loop.

Comment: Select shouldn't fail if it doesn't get any values though... it should just yield an empty result.